# How to save TS video stream with ffmpeg 2.0.2?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images, nas

The following command works well with ffmpeg 4.1

```
ffmpeg -i "http://example.com/index.m3u8" -vf fps=1/60 screen%04d.jpg -hide_banner
```

(it saves image every 1 minute from the stream)

But when I use version 2.0.2 I get

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'screen%04d.jpg'. 
screen%04d.jpg: Invalid argument
```

I have to use version 2.0.2 on my Synology NAS since this is pre-installed version.

How should I fix it?

Comment: Why not download a statich build of a modern FFmpeg and use this one?

Comment: Where can I download ffmpeg for my Synology DS210j?

Comment: Share full banner of your NAS ffmpeg build.

Comment: @Gyan, `ffmpeg version 2.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  4 2016 10:33:05 with gcc 4.6.4 (Marvell GCC release 20150204-c4af733b 64K MAXPAGESIZE ALIGN CVE-2015-0235)` (full data - https://pastebin.com/cZYNmMz4)

Comment: Alternatively, capture all the network packets in Wireshark, export the http objects, join them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a recent `ffmpeg` from [SynoCommunity](https://synocommunity.com/). As of this answer FFmpeg 4.1 is provided and includes support for your 88F628x architecture. [Installation instructions](https://synocommunity.com/#easy-install) from the SynoCommunity site:

1. Log into your NAS as administrator and go to **Main Menu → Package Center → Settings** and set Trust Level to *Synology Inc. and trusted publishers*.
2. In the **Package Sources** tab, click **Add**, type *SynoCommunity* as **Name** and *http://packages.synocommunity.com/* as **Location** and then press **OK** to validate.
3. Go back to the **Package Center** and enjoy SynoCommunity's packages in the **Community** tab.

For more info see the [SynoCommunity Wiki](https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc/wiki).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please clarify the package name? Can not find it at SynoCommunity repo.

Comment: @LA_ Is it not named "ffmpeg"? I can't actually test because I don't own one of these devices. Here's the link to the [spk file](https://packages.synocommunity.com/ffmpeg/11/ffmpeg.v11.f15047[88f628x].spk) if that helps. Also, according to [FAQ](https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) question *I can't find it in Package Center. What do I do?*: If you're using the search bar in Package Center, then select the drop-down arrow next to the magnifying glass, and set the value to `Community`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't upgrade, try

`ffmpeg -i "http://example.com/index.m3u8" -map 0:v -vf fps=1/60 -c:v mjpeg -q:v 2 -f segment -segment_time 0.01 -segment_format mjpeg screen%04d.jpg -hide_banner`

Comment: Thank you. `-hide_banner` is not supported. If I remove it, then I get `Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

Comment: @LA_ please move your comment to your real question. No need to reply this comment.

Comment: @Biswapriyo His comments relate to issues with my answer. Of course, it belongs here.

Comment: I mean the link.

Comment: That's not meant for the Q but as an aide to me to see if it's related to why my command didn't work.